# get all the images from camera roll and show it on the scroll view?

Tags: ios, image, memory, memory-management, alassetslibrary

Currently i am using ALasset library for fetching the images but when the images in the camera roll is in high amount i am getting the memory warning issues.

```
e.g assetsd died
```

this is my code to get the images from camera roll

```
[self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:(NSMakeRange(0, self.assetsGroup.numberOfAssets - 1))] options:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset result, NSUInteger index, BOOL stop)
             {
                 if (result)
                 {
                     UIImage *imageThumbnail;

                     imageThumbnail = [ImageHelper scaleAndRotateImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[result defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]] maxSize:500];

                     if(imageThumbnail)
                     {
                         //Do your code here….
                     }
             }];
```

How i can resolve the memory warning and asset died problem.
Also Can i known the apps which are having scroll view containing all the camera roll images but in scroll display not in grid form? So that i can get the reference of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are targrting ios8 onwards NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0) @interface PHAsset : PHObject

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion.. but my app in iOS 7 compatible too.. I can't use  PHAsset.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of scroll view you have to use collection view with `row = self.assetsGroup.numberOfAssets - 1` and in collection view cell write code as follow

```
[self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:(NSMakeRange(0, indexPath.row))] options:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset result, NSUInteger index, BOOL stop)
         {
             if (result)
             {
                 UIImage *imageThumbnail;

                 imageThumbnail = [ImageHelper scaleAndRotateImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[result defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]] maxSize:500];

                 if(imageThumbnail)
                 {
                     //Do your code here….
                 }
         }];
```

And one-thing more imageThumbnail size is in few kb so you can store it ( in local directory or in coredata usging nsdata )and before use enumerateAssetsAtIndexes check image is already stored then do not call use that stored image

Comment: thank you, but I have to display it in full screen so the few kb is not going to work and even if i use it my images will get distorted.

Comment: but i think when you using grid view at that time you have to only show Thumbnail image and for fullscreen mode i think you do not need to store it just fetch with ` [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:(NSMakeRange(0, indexPath.row))]` because in fullscreen mode you just need one image at time